# How to build a dynamic SQL expression that varies based on certain conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to build a query that selects an expression that differs based on certain conditions

```
DECLARE @program NVARCHAR(22) = 'test';
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @currency_results NVARCHAR(200) = '';
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

--where program = @program ) and currncy = 'T';
DECLARE results CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT result 
    FROM calcresult 
    WHERE calcfile = (SELECT calc_file 
                      FROM program 
                      WHERE program = @program)
     AND currncy = 'T';

OPEN results;
FETCH NEXT FROM results INTO @result;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @currency_results = @currency_results + '+' + @result ;
    PRINT @currency_results

    FETCH NEXT FROM results INTO @result
END

PRINT @currency_results

CLOSE results;
DEALLOCATE results;

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @currency_results + ' FROM tphase WHERE program = @program';

EXEC (@sql);
```

Initializing `@currency_results` fixed the last problem. However, now I am getting some kind of scope error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@program"

Comment: `SET @currency_results = @currency_results + '+' @result ;`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error but there are still no values getting into @currency_results

Comment: You have to give `@currency_results` an initial value before entering the loop, otherwise it starts out as `NULL`.  `NULL` + anything is `NULL`.

Comment: @brian or use CONCAT :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared @program in your outer procedure code that builds your sql string, but that doesn't mean it's available in the scope that is created when you EXEC your sql. Put the @prgram declaration in the sql string you built(the one you exec) viz

```
SET @sql = 'declare @program nvarchar(10) = ''' + @program + '''; 
select ' + @currency_results + ' from tphase where program = @program';
```

Or ditch it and put whatever value is in program in the string sql instead:

```
SET @sql = 'select ' + @currency_results + ' from tphase where program = ''' + @program + '''';
```

If the user is supplying the value for @program watch out for sql injection - use an appropriate method to guard against it - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 for how to use sp_executesql to run your parameterized dynamic sql. It might look something like this:

```
SET @sql = 'select ' + @currency_results + ' from tphase where program = @prog';
sp_executesql @sql, '@prog nvarchar(10)', @prog = @program;
```

I deliberately called it @prog and @program to more clearly show where the variables "live" (prog only exists inside the call to sp_executesql while program only exists outside it) and how this is working

Side note, using the CONCAT function to concatenate strings is more helpful where you don't want a null value nulling your entire string:

```
'A' + null + 'b' -- result: null string
CONCAT('A', null, 'b') -- result: Ab
```